# Using Onepage item.phtml from own Template

Tags: onepage-checkout

I am trying to edit the `onepage/review/item.phtml` to add specific attributes such as "sku" and "shippingtime".

In the onepage checkout a file is loaded from another (not base) template (i had to install  a module to be "german market ready"). I´ve deleted this `item.phtml` cause I thought Magento would load the `onepage/review/item.phtml` from the standard template or my template.

The folder structure should be ok:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/theme254k/template/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml
```

Magento is still loading the not existent `item.phtml` so there are no items in checkout (no item.phtml where Magento wants it).

Did I do something wrong? Why doesn't it load the "new" `item.phtml` even if old one does not exist?

Comment: Hi Jan and welcome to MageOverflow. I don't understand the question. Which files exist? Which files are deleted? Which file should be used? Which is used instead? Please have a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store maybe this solves already your problem.

Comment: Hi Fabian,
file loaded: `frontend/base/default/template/magesetup/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml`
I deleted this file and created a new one in:
`/app/design/frontend/default/theme254k/template/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml`

Magento is still loading the first one wich doesnt exists anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. undelete the file.

Second: If you don't use FireGento_MageSetup you did it right. But... you have to copy the right path, which is everything after `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template`, so in your case:

```
magesetup/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml
```

So if you create a file in

/app/design/frontend/default/theme254k/template/magesetup/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml

It should work

Comment: Thanks very much! The I didnt realize I need this extra `magesetup` folder. Works!