# modification "order review" in own theme doesn't work only in magesetup directory (1.9.0.1 CE)

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, onepage-checkout, review

I maybe have  a problem / found an error. I want to modify the order review for german markets, to display product images in order review. As far as I know:

Modify:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/my_theme/template/checkout/onepage/review/
info/item/totals.phtml
```

That doesn't work! Nor does

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/...
```

Changing info and totals does have an effect, but: Only changing the following file, has an effect on modification:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/magesetup/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml
```

Has anybody an explanation? Is there anaother way or did I miss something?

Comment: Hi there,seems that this is a similar issue: [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39879/using-onepage-item-phtml-from-own-template?rq=1). But why is there magesetup?

Answer (score 0):

I am making an assumption here but I guess since you mentioned that the site is for the German market at some point either [MageSetup](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-magesetup) has been used on your site. This extension was originally created to assist people setting up stores for the German market but has now been expanded to more countries.

What you can do is turn on template hints via the admin section to confirm if your templates are being overridden by MageSetup.